# Using a json schema in multiple layouts

Tags: jsonschema

I'm helping to build an interface that works with Json Schema, and I have a question about interface generation based on that schema. There are two display types - one for internal users and one for external users. Both are dealing with the same data, but the external users should see a smaller subset of fields than the internal users.

For example, here is one schema, it defines an obituary:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "id",
        "deceased"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "string" },
        "account": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [  
                "name"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "id": { "type": "number" },
                "name": { "type": "string" },
                "website": {
                    "anyOf": [  
                        {
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "uri"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "string",
                            "maxLength": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "email": {
                    "anyOf": [  
                        {
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "email"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "string",
                            "maxLength": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "address": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "address1": { "type": "string" },
                        "address2": { "type": "string" },
                        "city": { "type": "string" },
                        "state": { "type": "string" },
                        "postalCode": { "type": "string" },
                        "country": { "type": "string" }
                    }
                },
                "phoneNumber": {
                    "anyOf": [  
                        {
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "phone"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "string",
                            "maxLength": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "faxNumber": {
                    "anyOf": [  
                        {
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "phone"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "string",
                            "maxLength": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "type": { "type": "string" }
            }
        },
        "deceased": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [  
                "fullName"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "fullName": { "type": "string" },
                "prefix": { "type": "string" },
                "firstName": { "type": "string" },
                "middleName": { "type": "string" },
                "nickName": { "type": "string" },
                "lastName1": { "type": "string" },
                "lastName2": { "type": "string" },
                "maidenName": { "type": "string" },
                "suffix": { "type": "string" }
            }
        },
        "description": { "type": "string" },
        "photos": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": { "type": "string" }
        }
    }
}
```

Internal users would be able to access all the fields, but external users shouldn't be able to read/write the account fields.

Should I make a second schema for the external users, or is there a way to indicate different display levels or public/private on each field?

Comment: There are no access modifiers you can apply to json schema

Comment: So my only real option is to just make a second, very similar schema? That's fine, if that's the case, I just need to make sure before I go off in that direction.

Comment: Interface generation is not a part of JSON schema spec so you can use whatever access modifiers that the library you use for UI generation supports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restrict acess to the fields defined in a schema, but you can have 2 schema files, one defining the "public" fields, and the other one defining the restricted fields plus including the restricted fields.

So

public-schema.json:

```
{
    "properties" : {
        "id" : ...
    }  
}
```

restricted-schema.json:

```
{
    "allOf" : [
        {
            "$ref" : "./public-schema.json"
        },
        {
            "properties" : {
                "account": ...
            }
        }
    ]

}
```

Comment: Access is just out of scope, so this is not correct strictly speaking